# Java: Layout Button/Label Placement

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm trying to make a GUI pizza menu but I'm having trouble with the placements of the buttons/labels

```
public class PizzaGUI extends JFrame {

private JRadioButton rdoSmall;
private JRadioButton rdoMedium;
private JRadioButton rdoLarge;
private JRadioButton rdoExtraLarge;
private JLabel lblSize;
private ButtonGroup grpSize; 
JPanel panelSize;

private JCheckBox chkPepperoni;
private JCheckBox chkMushrooms;
private JCheckBox chkOlives;
private JCheckBox chkPineapple;
private JLabel lblToppings;
JPanel panelToppings;

private JRadioButton rdoSoda;
private JRadioButton rdoTea;
private JRadioButton rdoBottledWater;
private JRadioButton rdoTapWater;
private JLabel lblDrinks;
private ButtonGroup grpDrinks;
JPanel panelDrinks;

JPanel container;
JButton calculateTotal;
JLabel order;


PizzaGUI()
{
    super("Pizza Menu");

    setSize(600,500);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createPanel();

    add(container);

    setVisible(true);

}



public void createPanel()
{

    panelSize = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    panelToppings = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    panelDrinks = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));

    container = new JPanel();

    //Calculate Total
    calculateTotal = new JButton("Calculate");
    calculateTotal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95,45));


    order = new JLabel("Your Order:");


    //Pizza Sizes
    lblSize = new JLabel("Choose a size:");
    rdoSmall = new JRadioButton("Small ($7)");
    rdoMedium = new JRadioButton("Medium ($9)");
    rdoLarge = new JRadioButton("Large ($11)");
    rdoExtraLarge = new JRadioButton("Extra Large ($14)");

    //Toppings
    lblToppings = new JLabel("Choose toppings ($1 Each):");
    chkPepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
    chkMushrooms = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
    chkOlives = new JCheckBox("Olives");
    chkPineapple = new JCheckBox("Pineapple");

    //Drinks
    lblDrinks = new JLabel("Choose a drink:");
    rdoSoda = new JRadioButton("Soda ($2.00)");
    rdoTea = new JRadioButton("Tea ($1.50)");
    rdoBottledWater = new JRadioButton("Bottled Water ($1.25)");
    rdoTapWater = new JRadioButton("Tap Water (No charge)");


    //Add pizza sizes to button group
    grpSize = new ButtonGroup();
    grpSize.add(rdoSmall);
    grpSize.add(rdoMedium);
    grpSize.add(rdoLarge);
    grpSize.add(rdoExtraLarge);

    //Add drinks to button group
    grpDrinks = new ButtonGroup();
    grpDrinks.add(rdoSoda);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoTea);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoBottledWater);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoTapWater);

    //Add to panel
    panelSize.add(lblSize);
    panelSize.add(rdoSmall);
    panelSize.add(rdoMedium);
    panelSize.add(rdoLarge);
    panelSize.add(rdoExtraLarge);

    panelToppings.add(lblToppings);
    panelToppings.add(chkPepperoni);
    panelToppings.add(chkMushrooms);
    panelToppings.add(chkOlives);
    panelToppings.add(chkPineapple);

    panelDrinks.add(lblDrinks);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoSoda);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoTea);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoBottledWater);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoTapWater);

    container.add(panelSize);
    container.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
    container.add(panelToppings);
    container.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
    container.add(panelDrinks);
    container.add(calculateTotal);
    container.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
    container.add(order);


}





}
```

This the output
[Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Y5o1.png)

I have three separate grid layout panels for each type of menu and then I add it into one main panel which gets added to the frame. I would like to get the "Your Order:" placed in the middle left like the red one shown in the image. I know I can set the layout to null which would allow me to enter coordinates and it would solve my issue, however I read that it is bad practice to do it like that and I'm trying to effectively learn how to use layouts correctly. I don't even know if I'm on the right track, any examples would help. Thanks

Comment: You haven't set a layout manager on `container`, so it's probably getting a `FlowLayout` as a default.  Pick a different layout that gives you more control.  I[Read here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for information about some of the fine choices in layout managers available to you.  My personal favorite is `GridBadLayout`; it's probably the most flexible but not the easiest to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this can help you. 
You can add a seperate panel and then create a empty border for that panel.

```
container.add(panelSize);
container.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
container.add(panelToppings);
container.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
container.add(panelDrinks);
container.add(calculateTotal);


JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 200, 10, 700));
panel.add(order, BorderLayout.EAST);
container.add(panel);
```

[image: See this image]

Answer (score 0):

Your modified code it do what you want :

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class PizzaGUI extends JFrame {

private JRadioButton rdoSmall;
private JRadioButton rdoMedium;
private JRadioButton rdoLarge;
private JRadioButton rdoExtraLarge;
private JLabel lblSize;
private ButtonGroup grpSize; 
JPanel panelSize;

private JCheckBox chkPepperoni;
private JCheckBox chkMushrooms;
private JCheckBox chkOlives;
private JCheckBox chkPineapple;
private JLabel lblToppings;
JPanel panelToppings;

private JRadioButton rdoSoda;
private JRadioButton rdoTea;
private JRadioButton rdoBottledWater;
private JRadioButton rdoTapWater;
private JLabel lblDrinks;
private ButtonGroup grpDrinks;
JPanel panelDrinks;

JPanel container;
JButton calculateTotal;
JLabel order;


PizzaGUI()
{
    super("Pizza Menu");

    setSize(600,500);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    createPanel();

    add(container);

    setVisible(true);

}

public void createPanel()
{

    panelSize = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    panelToppings = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    panelDrinks = new JPanel(new GridLayout(5, 1));

    container = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
    JPanel container2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel placedOrderPanel =  new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    //Calculate Total
    calculateTotal = new JButton("Calculate");
    calculateTotal.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95,45));


    order = new JLabel("Your Order:");

    placedOrderPanel.add(new JLabel("Your Order placed"));

    //Pizza Sizes
    lblSize = new JLabel("Choose a size:");
    rdoSmall = new JRadioButton("Small ($7)");
    rdoMedium = new JRadioButton("Medium ($9)");
    rdoLarge = new JRadioButton("Large ($11)");
    rdoExtraLarge = new JRadioButton("Extra Large ($14)");

    //Toppings
    lblToppings = new JLabel("Choose toppings ($1 Each):");
    chkPepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
    chkMushrooms = new JCheckBox("Mushrooms");
    chkOlives = new JCheckBox("Olives");
    chkPineapple = new JCheckBox("Pineapple");

    //Drinks
    lblDrinks = new JLabel("Choose a drink:");
    rdoSoda = new JRadioButton("Soda ($2.00)");
    rdoTea = new JRadioButton("Tea ($1.50)");
    rdoBottledWater = new JRadioButton("Bottled Water ($1.25)");
    rdoTapWater = new JRadioButton("Tap Water (No charge)");


    //Add pizza sizes to button group
    grpSize = new ButtonGroup();
    grpSize.add(rdoSmall);
    grpSize.add(rdoMedium);
    grpSize.add(rdoLarge);
    grpSize.add(rdoExtraLarge);

    //Add drinks to button group
    grpDrinks = new ButtonGroup();
    grpDrinks.add(rdoSoda);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoTea);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoBottledWater);
    grpDrinks.add(rdoTapWater);

    //Add to panel
    panelSize.add(lblSize);
    panelSize.add(rdoSmall);
    panelSize.add(rdoMedium);
    panelSize.add(rdoLarge);
    panelSize.add(rdoExtraLarge);

    panelToppings.add(lblToppings);
    panelToppings.add(chkPepperoni);
    panelToppings.add(chkMushrooms);
    panelToppings.add(chkOlives);
    panelToppings.add(chkPineapple);

    panelDrinks.add(lblDrinks);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoSoda);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoTea);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoBottledWater);
    panelDrinks.add(rdoTapWater);

    container2.add(panelSize);
    container2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
    container2.add(panelToppings);
    container2.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(40));
    container2.add(panelDrinks);
    container2.add(calculateTotal);
    container2.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
    container2.add(order);
    container.add(container2);
    container.add(placedOrderPanel);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
  new PizzaGUI();
}
```

}

[image]